# How to store the results out of yield in a spider into a global variable?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I know how to get the result out of yield and save into to csv or json file, but how do I save it into a global variable or  maybe a local variable that I can pass as a function argument? I'm very new to scrapy.

Here's my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

global_var = {} # store the data result out of yield in this variable

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['worldpopulationreview.com']
    start_urls = ['https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/countries-by-national-debt/']

    def parse(self, response):
        country_data = response.xpath('//tbody/tr')
        for data in country_data:
            name = data.xpath('.//td[1]/a/text()').get()
            debt = data.xpath('.//td[2]/text()').get()
            population = data.xpath('.//td[3]/text()').get()
            link = data.xpath('.//td[1]/a/@href').get()

            yield {'country_name': name, 'country_debt': debt, 'country_population': population, 'country_url': response.urljoin(link)}


process = CrawlerProcess(
    settings={
        "FEEDS": {
            "result.json": {"format": "json"},
            "result.csv": {"format": "csv"},
        },
    }
)

process.crawl(TestSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: Unless scrapy.Spider expects the *parse* function to be a generator, this won't work. According to scrapy documentation "This method, as well as any other Request callback, must return an iterable of Request and/or item objects.". Your implementation does not fulfil that requirement

Answer (score 0):

```py
from scrapy import Spider


class TestSpider(Spider):

    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['worldpopulationreview.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        country_data = response.xpath('//tbody/tr')
        for data in country_data:
            name = data.xpath('.//td[1]/a/text()').get()
            debt = data.xpath('.//td[2]/text()').get()
            population = data.xpath('.//td[3]/text()').get()
            link = data.xpath('.//td[1]/a/@href').get()

            yield self.output_callback({
                'country_name': name,
                'country_debt': debt,
                'country_population': population,
                'country_url': response.urljoin(link)
            }) # instead of yield item
```

```py
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class Crawler:

    def __init__(self):
        self.process = CrawlerProcess()
        self.scraped_items = []

    def process_item(self, item): # similar to process_item in pipeline
        item.update({
            'scraped': 'yes'
        })
        self.scraped_items.append(item)
        return item

    def spawn(self, **kwargs):
        self.process.crawl(crawler_or_spidercls=TestSpider,
                           output_callback=self.process_item,
                           **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        self.process.start()
```

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    crawler = Crawler()
    crawler.spawn(
        start_urls=['https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/countries-by-national-debt/'])
    crawler.run()

    print(crawler.scraped_items)
```

Output

```py
[
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": None,
        "country_population": None,
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": "United States",
        "country_population": "29,463,730",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": "Japan",
        "country_population": "13,053,658",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": None,
        "country_population": "10,115,837",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": None,
        "country_population": "3,329,379",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": None,
        "country_population": "3,169,955",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": None,
        "country_population": "3,039,338",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": None,
        "country_population": "2,968,690",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": None,
        "country_population": "2,379,040",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": None,
        "country_population": "2,243,918",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": None,
        "country_population": "1,690,788",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": None,
        "country_population": "1,495,729",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": None,
        "country_population": "954,634",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": None,
        "country_population": "929,584",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": None,
        "country_population": "746,964",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": None,
        "country_population": "674,167",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": "Singapore",
        "country_population": "650,630",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": None,
        "country_population": "649,405",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": None,
        "country_population": "530,350",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": None,
        "country_population": "488,638",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    },
    {
        "country_name": None,
        "country_debt": "Greece",
        "country_population": "431,474",
        "country_url": "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt",
        "scraped": "yes",
    }
]
```

`process_item` is very useful for processing item as well as storing it.